How to manage dozens of outlook rules?
really, I have 50 or so rule, it's impossible to manage them in the small outlook rules popup window.
I would like at least to download them automatically so I can understand how to clean them up. It's extremely cumbersome
I'm just curious to understand how most people manage this basic task.
I believe I'm on the last version of Outlook, I believe 16, coming with updated MS Office 365

Expressing your frustration makes it less appealing for other users to help you.

Do you feel that your device display is too small to clear and manage multiple rules?

@Soki no, I'm on a big screen. Outlook pop up window for rules cannot be enalrged

@LPChip funny, I would say the contrary :-D I actually expressed the question as an user story..."as a user I would like to download rules, so that I can clean them up and re-upload them". Doesnt sound like a huge frustration...

No you're mistaken. Here are two snippets of your question that makes this emotional: "Its impossible to manage them..." "its extremely cumbersome". They add nothing to the question, and leaving that out will not make us feel like we no longer can answer it.

Is this a business environment? Are you Microsoft 365 enabled? Do you have a web mail view? Have you checked the rules there? What have you tried so far to "download" the rules? Yes, the classic Outlook rules window is small and ill suited to your extreme number of rules.
